# Discord.py bot responds to 2 if statements at the same time

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a leave command for my music module for my discord.py bot. I want the bot to say a message when someone uses `>leave` when the bot is not in a VC. I tried to write it out below but whenever the bot is in a VC and I type `>leave`, it says both messages below, but this does not happen when the bot is not in a VC. I do not get any errors at all. My question is, how can I get my bot to say, "I'm not even in a VC you weirdo." when someone uses `>leave` only when the bot is not is a VC?

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):

  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if voice.is_connected():
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.")

  if not voice.is_connected():
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when the `await voice.disconnect()` is executed, the `voice.is_connected()` will output false, because the bot is indeed disconnected from your previous command, so the if statement below the first if statement will get executed. There are two ways that you can fix it, one recommended way is to use `elif`, and the other would be switching the if statements around:

`elif` example

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):

  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if voice.is_connected():
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.")

  elif not voice.is_connected():
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")
```

switching around example

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):

  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if not voice.is_connected():
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")

  if voice.is_connected():
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.")
```

As knosmos pointed out in the comment you can also just use the else statement:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):

  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if voice.is_connected():
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.")
  else:
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an `else` statement instead of `elif` to make the code a bit cleaner:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):

  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

  if voice.is_connected():
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.")

  else:
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")
```

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work. When the bot is joined and i use >leave, it leaves and says i have left the vc though

Comment: huh, what happens now?

Comment: I'll edit the code to show you what i have. no errors as well

Answer (score 1):

Many people have explained what to do in previous answers. My below code should help you better understand your current logic.

```
x = True
if x:
    print('True')
    x = False
if not x:
    print('False')
```

First, we set x to True.
We then check if x is true. If so we can print that, and set x to false. Lastly we will check if x is false and sure enough it is. So we print false.

The same thing is happening with you. You check if you are connected, if so you leave. Then you check if you are not in a vc.

So like many people have said, you either use an elif statement to check if you are not in a vc or you can use an else statement.

correct

```
x = True
if x:
    print('True')
    x = False
elif not x:
    print('False')
`
```

Answer (score -2):

You are disconnecting the bot and checking if the bot is connected to any VC one after the other...

Use `elif`

Your current code:
if the bot is in a VC

```py
  voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild) #gets VC ID

  if voice.is_connected(): #This condition is true
    await voice.disconnect() #after this, voice.is_connected() is false
    await ctx.send("I have left the VC.") #print that

  elif not voice.is_connected(): #After the above, this is also true, use elif here
    await ctx.send("I'm not even in a VC you weirdo.")
```

Comment: you have not used elif